# Firefox Tab Favicon Mouse Events

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm writing a Firefox addon and I'd like to change the favicon when the user overs over it. My problem is that none of the usual callbacks getting fired. Here's what I've got so far.

This function gets called when tabs are restored or new tabs are created.

```
addPauseButtonToTab: function(tab)
{
    var icon = document.getAnonymousElementByAttribute(tab, "class", "tab-icon-image");
    icon.addEventListener('mouseover', savememory.showPauseButton, false);
    icon.addEventListener('mouseout', savememory.hidePauseButton, false);
    icon.addEventListener('click', savememory.blankFromButtonClick, false);
}
```

And here's the function that should get called when the mouse moves over the favicon.

```
showPauseButton: function(event)
{
   log('hello!');
}
```

The function never gets called. The string never gets logged. What's missing here?

Comment: I tried adding a `mouseover` event handler to a tab icon - works fine. It doesn't look like the problem is in the code you show here. You should double-check whether `addPauseButtonToTab` is ever called with the right tab.

Comment: I installed the extension on FF6/Win7, and the favicon hover code worked flawlessly. For some reason FF6/OSX 10.6.7 isn't as cooperative. Looks like the issue is related to my system somehow.